# SQL GROUP BY and SUM

Tags: sql, select, group-by, sum

List the continents with total populations of at least 100 million.

```
World Table

name         continent  area    population  gdp
Afghanistan  Asia       652230  25500100    20343000000
Albania      Europe     28748   2831741     12960000000
Algeria      Africa     2381741 37100000    188681000000
Andorra      Europe     468     78115       3712000000
Angola       Africa     1246700 20609294    10009000990
...
...
```

I started with

`SELECT continent FROM world WHERE ...` and kind of got stuck here.

Not sure how I can leverage GROUP BY and SUM. I need to `GROUP BY continent` and 
`SUM(population)` some how but I am still learning how to put things together.

expected output

```
continent
Africa
Asia
Eurasia
Europe
North America
South America
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT   continent, SUM(population)
FROM     world
GROUP BY continent
HAVING   SUM(population) >= 100000000
```

Comment: If that answered your question, it's best to mark the answer. By clicking the tick.

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you a good framework for thinking through this question.

Since there are multiple records with the same continent, we know we need GROUP BY. Once we do group by, we can use aggregate operations to get the sum, namely SUM. By using this aggregate operation, we can filter using the HAVING clause post group-by. If we wanted to filter pre-groupby, we would use the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT continent FROM world GROUP BY continent HAVING SUM(population) > 
100000000;
```