# SQL: how to group and sum?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to make a simple PostgreSQL query but I am not an expert.

I have this table that shows sales:

[image: Sells table]

I need to show how much each seller sold by day. This is the results that I need:

[image: SQL results]

I check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25174862/sql-group-by-and-sum) but I need to group by date too.

I tried this but I can't get what I need:

```
SELECT seller, date, sum(amount) AS amount
FROM sales
GROUP BY seller, date, amount
ORDER BY seller;
```

Comment: Are you getting an error messages or the wrong result?

Comment: @RobySottini Are you sure that yor desired table result are correct? I can't think of thow to get $80 for John on 2020-06-01 ?

Comment: @Ben Wrong results.

Comment: @RobySottini  What result are you getting?

Comment: Your desired results is not showing the expected outcome but you don't need to include amount in the group by. Check my answer.

Comment: @Grace Sorry. I just changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that you want to group up the amount for each seller per each day, the sql should be as below.

```
SELECT seller, date, sum(amount) AS amount
FROM sales
GROUP BY seller, date
ORDER BY date, seller;
```

Comment: @RobySottini Pls see if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT seller, date, sum(amount) AS amount
FROM sales
GROUP BY seller, date
ORDER BY seller,date;
```

Comment: Don't you also want to order by date?

Comment: It depends but yes it is pretty to have order by date as well otherwise might have to scratch the head to read results. edited my code

Comment: I realized that my date fields also have times like 2020-06-02 20:24:45.652280 so it can't be grouped. That was the problem. My fault.